# Bind disable attribute dynamically for each row for disabling button row-wise in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a situation in LWC. In a table there are multiple records coming dynamically with selection of available dropdowns. Each row has Approve and Reject button functionality. I have managed Approve and Reject by a custom field. Here after Approval/Rejection I want to disable buttons for selected approved row only.
But because of same disable attribute it disables approve/reject buttons for all unselected rows - that I don't want. I want button disable for only selected row..
Disable attribute in Lightning button for approve/reject is same. disable=(isDisabledButton). How could I achieve this scenario?

HTML CODE

```html
<template for:each={materialMap} for:item="item">
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={item.id}>
        <td class="slds-cell-wrap" scope="col" >
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap">
                {item.materialName__c}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="slds-cell-wrap" scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap">
                {item.avgCount}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="slds-cell-wrap" scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap">
                {item.totalValue}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="slds-cell-wrap" scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap">
                {item.discountedValue}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td if:true={showApproveRejectbutton} class="slds-cell-wrap" scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap">
                <lightning-button variant="success" name={item.materialName__c} label="Approve" title="Successful action" onclick={handleApproval} class="slds-m-left_x-small" disabled={isDisabledButton}>
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td if:true={showApproveRejectbutton} class="slds-cell-wrap" scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap">
                <lightning-button variant="destructive" name={item.materialName__c} label="Reject" title="Destructive action" onclick={handleApproval} class="slds-m-left_x-small" disabled={isDisabledButton}>
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

JS

```javascript
handleApproval(event){              
    const actionButton = event.target.name;
    let selectedButton= event.currentTarget.name; 
    console.log('selectedButton '+selectedButton);
    let objIndx = this.materialMap.findIndex((item => item.materialName__c== selectedButton));
    console.log('objIndx== '+objIndx);
    let buttonvalue= this.materialMap[objIndx].isDisabledButton=true;
    console.log('Name of buttonvalue  = '+JSON.stringify(buttonvalue));
}
```

For this

`console.log('Name of buttonvalue  = '+JSON.stringify(buttonvalue));`

I am getting true value but it is not disabling the button[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.materialMap= []; 
 this.totalValues.forEach(element1 => { 
 this.materialMap= [...this.materialMap, {}]; 
 this.materialMap[this.materialMap.length - 1]['key']=this.materialMap.length-1; 
 this.materialMap[this.materialMap.length - 1]['materialName__c'] = element1.materialName__c; 
 this.materialMap[this.materialMap.length - 1]['avgCount'] =element1.avgCount; 
 this.materialMap[this.materialMap.length - 1]['isDisabledButton'] = this.isDisabledButton; });

 JS
 handleApproval(event){              
 const actionButton = event.target.name;
 let selectedButton= event.currentTarget.name; 
 console.log('selectedButton '+selectedButton);
 let objIndx = this.materialMap.findIndex((item => item.materialName__c== selectedButton));
 console.log('objIndx== '+objIndx);
 let buttonvalue= this.materialMap[objIndx].isDisabledButton=true;
 console.log('Name of buttonvalue  = '+JSON.stringify(buttonvalue));
 }
  In above code every thing is fine.. I missed to make materialMap[] reactive..I have defined it as @track materialMap[]; its working.. 
Thanks @prabuddh kumar for your suggestion about disable attribute item.isDisabledButton.
```

Comment: awesome that you figured out how to implement it. If my answer/comment helped, kindly upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community.

In your question you have also pointed out the flaw in this approach "***Disable attribute in lightning button for approve/reject is same***".

To achieve this, I would suggest **having "disabled" attribute as part of the Data on which you are iterating, so that you can use "item.disabled" instead of the current boolean (isDisabledButton**).

when you select something, in the change handler just update the disabled to true for that item in your js file.

Comment: Hii Prabuddh Kumar thank for replying.. I hv already added isDisabledButton in Array  this.materialMap= [];    
    this.totalValues.forEach(element1 => {   
        this.materialMap= [...this.materialMap, {}];
        this.materialMap[this.materialMap.length - 1]['key'] =this.materialMap.length - 1;
        this.materialMap[this.materialMap.length - 1]['materialName__c'] = element1.materialName__c;
        this.materialMap[this.materialMap.length - 1]['avgCount'] =element1.avgCount;
          this.materialMap[this.materialMap.length - 1]['isDisabledButton'] = this.isDisabledButton;
});

Comment: ok. Then you need to pass the "item.isDisabledButton" value in the disabled attribute of the buttons

Comment: did but not worked.. is there any other way to target that row button only...actually this array totalValues is coming from Aggregated Query

Comment: can you share what changes you made ? Ideally this is the best way to achieve selective targeting of the rows

Comment: in HTML I have added disabled={item.isDisabledButton}

Comment: print the "materialMap" in console and add the screenshot here

Comment: added please check above in the question..Here I am not getting Disabled attribute

Comment: yeah , that's the issue. Seems like you haven't added the disabled attribute to the map correctly.

Comment: materialMap seems to be an array of Object. as soon as you get the materialMap, iterate over the array and add an attribute called "isDisabled" with the value as false for all the array elements. Then on the click of the button, make it true for the respective array element

Comment: something like this :     
   materialMap.forEach(item =>{
    item.isDisabled = false;
});

Comment: And in your handleApproval function, access the element using the key and toggle the isDisabled boolean

Comment: Now I m getting isDisabledButton Attribute in MaterialMap Array. I hv did following changes in JS but not working .   let buttonvalue= this.newArrayforLocationTable[objIndx].isDisabledButton;
        if(buttonLabel === 'Approve'){
           buttonvalue=true;
                          
        }

Comment: one more thing I am nit getting {item.isDisabledButton}  in HTML of Button <button class="slds-button slds-button_success" name="Sparker-Pink112" title="Successful action" type="button">Approve</button>